# will angular2 have the kendo spreadsheet?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, spreadsheet

Will angular2 in any upcoming release have the Kendo Spreadsheet or the export to excel for the grid.? We would like to have the Spreadsheet version in angular2 since we are using the angular1 version and like to upgrade. Will this be possible.

Grid example [Click here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export)

Spread Sheet Example
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/index

If not is there a way to incorporate spreadsheet into angular2 application?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Question about references to tools, libraries, tutorials are discouraged on SO. Please ask on other channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt matter which angular version you are using , if you want to access methods in another script.this is how you should do it using angular2

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

include these scripts in your index.html and in order to access these use `declare` and create a `variable` of type `any` inside your `service`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare graphs:any;
//graphs represents the scripts you have imported from index.html 

@Injectable()
export class GraphService {

  constructor() { }

  dosomethingWithgraphs(){
   graphs.methods()//accessing its methods
   graphs.properties//accessing its properties
  }
}
```